# jQuery not calling my function?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have recently started learning jquery to improve my website. I wanted to make a login modal dialog for users to input their credentials on... I started with this code:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
        size: BootstrapDialog.size_normal,
        title: 'Login',
        message: '\
        <form name="LoginUser" method="POST" action="php/process.php">\
            \
            <div class="input-group">\
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>\
                <input name="Username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">\
            </div><br>\
            \
            <div class="input-group">\
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>\
                <input name="Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">\
            </div><br>\
            \
        </form> \
        \
        Forgot your password? Click here!\
        ',

        buttons: 
        [
            {id: 'btn-login', icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', label: 'Login', cssClass: 'btn-primary',  autospin: true, action: function() { 
                $('LoginUser').submit(function() {
                    if(window.console) console.log('foo');

                    /*var UserData = {
                        'UserName'      : $('input[name=name]').val(),
                        'PassWord'      : $('input[name=name]').val(),
                    };

                    $.ajax({
                        type        : 'POST', 
                        url         : 'php/process.php', 
                        data        : formData, 
                        dataType    : 'json', 
                        encode      : true
                    })*/
                });
            }},

            {id: 'btn-cancel', icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove', label: 'Cancel', cssClass: 'btn-primary',  autospin: false, action: function(dialogRef){ 
                dialogRef.close(); 

            }}
        ]
    });
```

The button does not seem to call the `$('LoginUser').submit(function()` function that i put there below.. i tried console testing but nothing seems to be working even console.log logs...

EDIT: the modal dialog is [nakupanda's Bootstrap Dialog on GitHub](http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/#available-options)

EDIT2: Can anyone try to re-write it for me? cause i dont think i am getting anywhere

EDIT3: I have re-written the code and my only problem is how will php know that it came from jquery and is the specific form its supposed to operate on?

```
{id: 'btn-login', icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', label: 'Login', cssClass: 'btn-primary',  autospin: false, action: function() { 

                    var formData = { 
                        'UserName' : $('input[name="Username"]').val(), 
                        'PassWord' : $('input[name="Password"]').val() 
                    };

                    $.post('php/process.php', function(formData) {
                        console.log("foo3")
                        $('#LoginUser').submit(function(formData) {
                            console.log("foo")
                        });
                    })

                    /*.done(function(data) {
                        console.log(data)

                        if (!data.success) {
                            alert("Failed!")
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Success!")
                        }
                    });*/
                    event.preventDefault();
            }},
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['LoginUser']))
{
    $errors =   Array();
    $data =     Array();

    echo $_POST['Username']; 
    echo $_POST['Password'];

    if(empty($_POST['Username'])) $errors['Username'] = 'Username is required.';
    if(empty($_POST['Password'])) $errors['Password'] = 'Password is required.';

    if(!empty($errors['Username']) && !!empty($errors['Password'])) 
    {   
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = 'Success!';
    } 
    else
    {
        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['errors']  = $errors;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: LoginUser is id or class if it is ID then call like this $("#LoginUser").submit(function()) else if it class then  $(".LoginUser").submit(function()).check once

Comment: done it.. still the same

Comment: what is LoginUser field is it ID or class or tag name

Comment: I am echoing the form thru jquery.... its a name

Comment: can you create fiddle to show this issue...?

Comment: i dont know how to use jsfiddle.. 0.o

Comment: The action is called when the button is submitted, makes no sense to bind to a form submission when the button is clicked. Just make the Ajax call in the action.

Comment: How will i do that? :O

Comment: get rid of the submit handler code....??

Comment: Hmm without the form handle thing.. How will i check the data on php?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to submit the form by using the name selector you need to follow the syntax given below

```
$("form[name='LoginUser']").submit()
```

If you are having only one form then the follwoing will work

```
$("form").submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's not too late.

Try replacing button definition as below:

```js
{id: 'btn-login', icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', label: 'Login', cssClass: 'btn-primary',  autospin: true, action: function(dialog) { 
                dialog.getModalBody().find('form').submit(function() {
                  ....
```

And you don't actually need to write your form like that way, this would be better:

```js
message: function(dialog) {
  var $form = $('<form />');
  ...
  
  return $form;
}
```

You can even bind the form reference to the dialog instance and use it later:

```js
message: function(dialog) {
  var $form = $('<form />');
  ...
  
  // Bind $form to dialog instance
  dialog.setData('myform', $form);
  
  return $form;
},
buttons: [{
  label: 'A button',
  action: function(dialog) {
    var $form = dialog.getData('myform');
    
    $form.submit();
  }
}]
```

A better fashion.